# Overflow not working correctly on jQuery slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

Vey simple slider using jQuery but for some reason the viewport resizes and won't hide them offscreen when using a left-margin: 100% when the banner class is 100% width.

Any ideas?  If you do know a way around that would also be great.  The code is also located on my Github if that helps:  https://github.com/shaggywolfhound/Tiislider

```
HTML: -
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My project</title>
<meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
<meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<link rel="image_src" href="../images">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="carouselbanner">
    <ul class="banners">
    <li class="banner displayed"><img src="images/delivery.png" /></li>
    <li class="banner"><img src="images/sameDay.png" /></li>
    <li class="banner"><img src="images/trustpilot.png" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<article>
</article>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var $current = 2;
/*$('.banners').on('click', function() {*/

function banners() {
$('.banners').find('.displayed').toggleClass('displayed');
$('.banners').find('.banner').filter(':nth-child(' + $current + ')').addClass('displayed');
$current=$current+1;
if ($current==4) {$current=1;}
};
setInterval(banners,2000);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

Sass: -

@import 'reset';
@import 'var';
@import 'transitions';

.carouselbanner {
background-color: $grey;
height: 200px;
margin: 0;
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

.banners {
height: auto;
//overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;

.banner {
//border: 1px solid $black;
margin-left: 100%;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
z-index: 100;

img {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  }

  &.displayed {
  margin-left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: easeOutQuart;
  z-index: 200;
  img {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually my fault it does work correctly.  I just misunderstood how Chrome displays something when it has gone outside the viewport.